# Plugins for creating and styling custom Editor Windows like C#/C++ Form Designer or “Web Inspector”?

Tags: unity, tools

`Unity3d` allows to construct window with custom UI. Just need to use `EditorGUI/EditorGUILayout` classes and their static methods.
Example of custom window:

[image]

The problem is that all the components have to be added manually via script. Then need to save, switch to Editor, wait for little compile things, and then we can see the result.

In web-development people use `Web Inspector` (for example, we can press <kbd>F12</kbd> in `chrome`, Tab `Elements` -> `Styles`). We can add all needed properties to element and can see the result in real-time.

[image]

**EDIT.** another example (better than previous): we know `C# winFormApp`, `C++ MFC` e.t.c, which has form designer. We can choose any elements and set their properties:
[image]

It would be nice to have similar plugins for Unity

So. Does `Unity3d` have similar tools, utilities, plugins? Utilities to inspect code and editing styles (position, margin, padding, background, width, height, color  e.t.c.)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found something interesting...[Editor window designer](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-extension-editor-window-designer.337474/)

The plugin is almost what I need

The project had been started but not completed yet.
As [the author says](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rel-open-source-editor-window-designer.375900/): he decided to release Editor Window Designer as an open source project, that code [is here](https://github.com/ahrenm/uAssist)

For now plugin allows add elements and styling them (position, padding, width, height, e.t.c)
Base demo window:

[image: img1]

And here is hierarchy window and properties of concrete element

[image: img2]

I wonder why Unity developers (or someone else) still didn't do something like that?  It is very useful and necessary thing...

Comment: good find. Any idea how to integrate this into unity. Do I just put the source code in a Editor folder?

Comment: @UriPopov You can just put "uAssist" folder (wich contains "EditorDesigner" and "UEditorWidgets") in the root (Asset folder). And that's all... Then in menu you can find: `Window->uAssist->WindowDesigner->Create New Form/Edit Form`
 ...... also at the bottom of the page http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-extension-editor-window-designer.337474/#post-2446798 you can find the package

Answer (score 0):

No, since the scripts are compiled (before run) and therefore can't be manipulated at runtime. However: you could add debug fields to your scripts to change certain fields (let's say a color or so).

Comment: Not run-time. I wrote "real-time". It's different... I guess)) 
....Well, Form designer in `c# winFormApp` does not compile Form every N-seconds or M-actions. It keeps state of the fields in some variables and then (when `saveBtn` was clicked) just adds lines to the File (Form.cs,  xml and others)....
And it is possible to do the same in Unity. 100% ...It can be hard, but really posssible)) Even do not need to compile anything

Comment: And my answer was meant to describe the status quo. Sure you could do a designer and generate a respective script, but this would be quite a lot of work. Regarding run-time: since you spoke about chrome inspector I thought you'd mean run-time.